# r Change line width of eigenvectors in autoplot pca

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, autoplot

In R, one can easily display eigenvectors in PCA ordination plots using the autoplot function from the ggfortify package, as per the sample code below:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(ggrepel)

data(iris)
df <- iris[1:4]

pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)

plt <- plot(autoplot(
  pca_res,
  data = iris,
  colour = 'Species',
  label.size = 3,
  loadings = TRUE,
  loadings.colour = "red",
  loadings.label = TRUE,
  loadings.label.repel = TRUE,
  loadings.label.size = 3
))

plt
```

With such code, it is possible to control the colours of eigenvectors, however I could not find any way of changing the line width of the eigenvectors.

Could someone tell how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly within the function call, but you can do it indirectly after the object is created.

Your code creates the following plot:

```r
plt
```

[image]

But if we do

```r
plt$layers[[2]]$aes_params$size <- 3
```

Then we change it to

```r
plt
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>